# Java script is ignoring setInterval currently in a infinte loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently doing a tortoise and the hare homework assignment. I am supposed to display the tortoise and the hare moving around until they hit 70 tiles and then the script ends. Everything is currently working except that it is displaying all the moves at once, but I want it to show 1 move every second, but it is currently ignoring my setInterval. Below is my code.

Edit: I have fixed it so it shows one move at a time but now once it reaches the end it continues to go after a winner has been picked. I think I have some kind of infinite loop with setInterval but I am just not sure where I need to edit my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tortoise and hare</title>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

        var posH = 1;
        var posT = 1;
        var track = new Array (70); 

        var intervalId; 




        function outputArray(theArray)
        {
            document.writeln("<table border = \"1\"");
            document.writeln("<tbody><tr>");
            var toPrint = "&nbsp;";
            for (var i = 1; i <= theArray.length; i++)
            {
                toPrint = "&nbsp;";
                if (i == posT) toPrint = "T";
                if (i == posH) toPrint = "H";
                if ((i == posT) && (i == posH)) toPrint = "OUCH!!!"; 
                document.writeln("<td>" + toPrint + "</td>");
            }
            document.writeln("</tr></tbody></table>");
        } 

        for (var i = 0;i < track.length; ++i)
            track[i] = i;
        outputArray(track);

        function updateClock(){

            moveposT();
            moveposH();

            if (posT > 69) posT = 69;
            if (posH > 69) posH = 69;
            outputArray(track);
            if ((posH >= 69) || (posT >= 69))
                raceEnds();

        } 

        function raceStarts(){
            document.write("BANG !!!!!<br/>AND THEY'RE OFF !!!!!<br/>");
            outputArray(track);
            intervalId = window.setInterval(updateClock, 100);
        } 
        function moveposT(){
            i = Math.floor( Math.random() * 11);

            if ((i >= 1) && (i <= 5)){ 
                posT = posT + 3;       

            }
            if ((i >= 6) && (i <= 7)){ 
                posT = posT - 6;    

            }
            if ((i >= 8) && (i <= 10)){
                posT = posT + 1;     

            }
            if (posT < 1){             
                posT = 1;          

            }

        } 
        function moveposH()
        {
            i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

            if ((i >= 1) && (i <= 2)){
                posH = posH + 0;      

            }
            if ((i >= 3) && (i <= 4)){
                posH = posH + 9;      

            }
            if (5 == i){             
                posH = posH - 12;    

            }
            if ((i >= 7) && (i <= 8)){
                posH = posH + 1;    

            }
            if ((i >= 9) && (i <= 10)){
                posH = posH - 2;      

            }
            if (posH < 1){            
                posH = 1;           

            }

        } 

    function raceEnds()

    {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        if ((posT == 69 ) && (posH == 69 ))
            document.write("<br/><br/><b>It's a tie.</b>");
        else {
            if (posT >= 69)
            {
                posT = 69 ;
                document.write("<br/><br/><b>Tortoise wins!!! Yay!!!</b>");
            }
            if (posH >= 69)
            {
                posH = 69 ;
                document.write("<br/><br/><b>Hare wins.Yuck!</b>");
            }
        }
    } 

</script>
</head>
<body onload="raceStarts();">


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are passing the *result* of `updateClock` to setInterval. You  need to pass the function itself without calling it (i.e. without the `()`). It also looks like you are calling `window.setInterval` many times and will have a lot of timers running at once.

Comment: Yes that was exactly what I had to do I just had to pass the function itself without calling it. Also like you said I do have multiple timers going at once I am just trying to debug it right now and figure out where it needs to be deleted. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In respect to @MarkMeyer's comment:

> You are passing the result of `updateClock` to `setInterval`. You need to pass the function itself without calling it (i.e. without the `()`). It also looks like you are calling `window.setInterval` many times and will have a lot of timers running at once.

Comment: Answer is by @MarkMeyer , please don't simply copy paste the answer.

Comment: Yes once it completes it atleast once it just keeps on going to a new one. I am not sure where I need to fix my setIntervals so that after a winner is picked it will stop instead of calling it again.